# Cant upload files in google bucket using php

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cloud, google-cloud-storage

I am using google appengine to upload files in php, but it is not uploaded. To upload file first i downloaded  the app engine. After that inside the app engine i made my project folder say ie cloud(google_appengine/php/sdk/cloud).

**Inside cloud in app.yaml**

```
application: cloud
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: cloud.php
```

**In php.ini**

```
; This is a simple php.ini file on App Engine
; It enables output buffering for all requests by overriding the
; default setting of the PHP interpreter.
output_buffering = "On"
max_file_uploads = 10
upload_max_filesize = 100M
session.gc_maxlifetime = 10000
google_app_engine.allow_include_gs_buckets = "#default#, test_bucket_content"
```

**In cloud.php**

```
<?php
require_once '../google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php';

use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

$options = [ 'gs_bucket_name' => 'syncspot-ds.appspot.com'];
echo $upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload_handler.php', $options);
exit;
```

I am not getting the upload url. In cloudStorageTools.php, there is some issue after $req & $resp.

```
public static function createUploadUrl($success_path, $options = array()) {
        $req = new CreateUploadURLRequest();
        $resp = new CreateUploadURLResponse();

    ....
    }
```

I guess it isnot connectiong with the bucket. I am using google_appengine_1.9.23 and "test_bucket_content" is my bucket name. Please tell where i am doing the mistake??

Comment: syncspot-ds is my project id

Comment: With this code I am getting this error 
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/google_appengine/php/sdk/cloud/cloud.php". And suppose if i print something after $resp(cloudStorageTools.php), It is not responding.

Comment: Quick look at your code, you say your bucket is "test_bucket_content" but in your code you are using 'syncspot-ds.appspot.com' for the bucket. Are you getting any errors or just not seeing your files? If you go to the console do you see your files listed?

Comment: Are you having this problem when the app is deployed? Or only when running locally?

Comment: I am getting this issue when running locally. And syncspot-ds is my project id. I followed this url for this(https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload). Do we have to put our project folder inside the app engine?? Beside that in http://console.developers.google.com/ VM Instances for lamp server I dont have permissions like Permissions
User info Disabled=====
Compute Read Only====
Storage Disabled====
Task queue Disabled==
BigQuery Disabled==
Cloud SQL Disabled==
Cloud Datastore Disabled==
Cloud Logging Write Only==
Cloud Monitoring Disabled==
Cloud Platform Disabled